# How to write a polite quotation request email?

Tags: description

Good day! I'm working at Sales Dept. in a manufacturing enterprise. Lately my company strategy is to find other suppliers to have more competitive prices and I appointed to do this task. But I make a trouble now about the ideas as well as the contents how to write quotation request to them. There are a lot of suppliers (in textile sector) i have in hand and i don't want to just write some paragraphs then copy & past them to send to all. I'm a newcomer here, I hope to have your kind supports. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  We can't tell you what to write (the actual *content* of that message), which leaves the question of how to structure it in a polite and professional manner.  That's been asked before, so I'm marking this as a duplicate.  Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Ask a person from the supply dept - how they request supplies from 3rd party companies - raw materials, equipment, machines, whatever your company needs but doesn't manufacture. Phrase your quote request just the same, just exchange the articles you're asking for.

In particular, in your situation, there's really nothing wrong about copy&paste to multiple recipients. It's strictly a business letter, not some kind of courtesy mail like thank-you, congratulations or apology letters, so "personal touches" are really not necessary.